# I installed an node.js module locally from a repository but it cannot find the module

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, dependencies, node-modules

I'm working on a fork of this project https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-interface-v1 which has a dependency @pancakeswap-libs/uikit.

I need to work on this dependency and I can do it, but every time I do npm install, the modifications are overwritten. The ideal setup is to have this dependency in my workspace folder as well, installed locally.

https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-toolkit/tree/master/packages/pancake-uikit
This is the dependency repository. I tried to put the folder inside my project, more specifically the pancake-toolkit/packages/pancake-uikit folder.

Then I installed it locally, this is my main package.json:

> "@pancakeswap-libs/uikit": "file:pancake-uikit",

When I'm trying to import something like the normal dependency it was, it cannot find the module.

For example, when I try to `import { ResetCSS } from '@pancakeswap-libs/uikit'` [here](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-interface-v1/blob/master/src/index.tsx).

I've done a lot of research and I can't seem to fix the problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you need to fork the dependency too and change your main fork to use your forked dependency.

Comment: @jfriend00 Can you be more specific? Or point in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

1. After downloading the project
2. Open project directory in our terminal
3. type the following commands

`npm install or yarn install`